# Unit Testing Callbacks in Scala.js

Tags: scala, unit-testing, callback, scala.js

Hi so I have an actor model set up using Akka, and I am setting up a JS facade using callbacks.

Pretty much each actor does some kind of long computation and calls a js provided callback with the results.

I want to unit test this but having issues figuring out a way to do it. It isn't a response but rather something the actor calls when finished.

I need a way to use an assertion inside of the a function literal. Like below.

```
val cb = (result: Double): Unit => {
  assert(result == Math.PI)
}
```

And then I can pass it to the actor.

```
mathActor ! Compute("foo", cb)
```

The actor then does computations and calls cb.

```
case Compute(foo, cb) =>
    // compute foo
    cb(foo)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I haven't used Akka.js at all, so I don't know the implications of that. But in principle, it seems like you probably need a Promise/Future pair, where your test would create a Promise, which gets completed inside the callback, and depends on the corresponding Future to resolve.

So in principle, it would be something like this. (Mind, this is airy theory, not something I've actually tried.)

```
def checkMyDouble():Future[Double] = {
  val promise = Promise[Double]
  val cb = (result: Double): Unit => {
    promise.success(result)
  }
  mathActor ! Compute("foo", cb)
  promise.future
}

checkMyDouble.map { result =>
  assert(result == Math.PI)
}
```

The notion here is that your unit test needs a Future that it can be waiting for, so it knows when it is complete. Futures come from Promises, so you kind of inevitably want to have a Promise involved somewhere in the mix.

Note that the above doesn't have any sort of timeout, which you'll also want, but it should give you at least an idea of possible directions...

Answer (score 0):

I posted here an example that try to reproduce the example that you explained: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/xl9mtYG/0 I hope it is of help.

Moreover I have to say that the ask pattern is supported in Akka.Js and you can leverage it for facades:

```
import akka.pattern._
(mathActor ? Compute("foo")).map(cb)
```

a basic complete example of ask pattern here: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/yNDVuLn/0

Please feel free to ask if there is any missing bit in this answer.